# Migrate Linq.Binary to binary(16)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class with `Linq.Binary` property, which I wish to map to `binary(16)` in database. By default, this type isn't mapped when creating new migration.

Changing from `Linq.Binary` to `byte[]` didn't help, because I can't found a way to set length of `binary()` in database.

1. `[MaxLength(16)]` data annotation didn't work.
2. Fluent API: `modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(x => x.BinaryProperty).HasMaxLength(LengthOfBinaryField).IsFixedLength();` didn't work too.

What can I do for a `Linq.Binary` (or `byte[]`) to make sure the column that gets created is a `binary(16)` in the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Entity Framework version?

Comment: I've tried with 'byte[]' property and your option 2 did work - resulted in  `binary(16)` column in the db table